# HTML-CSS. Как добавить стрелку в этот код?

Tags: html, css

Как добавить в `span` `::before`, также как на скрине?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
У меня в футере так:

```html
<div class="back-to-top-link"><a href="#top"><span class="arrow"></span>Top</a></div>
```

Из-за этого отсутствует стрелка...

Answer (score 3):

Это псевдоэлемент. `::before` нельзя добавить в html явно. Его используют в CSS таблицах стилей. В вашем случае это будет примерно так:

```
.arrow:before {...}
```

Подробней о `:before` можно почитать [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/before).

Answer (score 3):

Через `CSS`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.back-to-top-link {
  position: relative;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  text-align: center;
}

.back-to-top-link::before {
  content: "\2191";
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  color: #000;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="back-to-top-link"><a href="#top">Top</a></div>
```

Comment: В стилях у меня он прописан:

Comment: @Артем, не совсем понял. Вы пытались добавить псевдоэлемент в `HTML`? В ответе ниже расписано, как добавлять псевдоэлементы. Я привёл вам пример на `CSS`.

Comment: Я добавил правила в CSS файле. Если не сложно - можете посмотреть: http://demo1.argisty.com - это то, что у меня на данный момент получается; это как нужно сделать - transit-dk.com/#global-reach

Нет возможности вставить CSS код сюда (длина не позволяет)

Comment: Вы не смогли добавить спецсимвол потому, что написали в content: "e02d", а не "\e02d", или выберите другой. http://bloggood.ru/vebmasteru/specsimvoly-dlya-html-i-css.html/  https://github.com/jasonsanjose/compass-example/blob/master/bower_components/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.styl

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, это спецсимвол Bootstrap, который вы хотели использовать. Если вам помог данный ответ - отметьте его "решением"

Answer (score 2):

```css
.arrow:after {
  font-family: 'squarespace-ui-font';
  content: "^";
  font-weight: 900;
  color;
  #222;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.arrow:hover:after {
  animation: move 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -10px);
  }
}
```

если так сделаете то появится вот такой элемент у вас 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]